# Canadian Citizen with Paypal Account with US funds

Tags: united-states, paypal

My sister-in-law is a Canadian Citizen.  She works in the US and has a US Bank account.  She also has a Paypal Account that is in US dollars.

She wants to  send me $20,000 via Paypal (I am a US Citizen) and then have me send it to a company in the US who is providing a service to her.

Would I get into trouble if I am the go between?
She doesn't want to convert her Paypal money to Canadian funds, and then back to US as it would cost her $3000.
Would this get me in trouble with Homeland Security?
Would this cause me to have a tax liability?

Comment: If she has a US Bank Account, what is stopping her from directly transferring this from her Bank Account to the US Companies bank Account?

Comment: What @Dheer said. It is highly unlikely that your sister-in-law is scamming you, but were not a relative, it would scream scam.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. There is no reason for using a middle-person, the funds don't need to be currency converted, and even if the funds did need to be converted, it wouldn't cost 15% to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your sister-in-law should know that **anybody, US citizen or not,** can open a US bank account. She should do that and then pay her 20k fee to the company.

I'm a Canadian citizen and I have a US bank account and I don't even live nor work in the United States. I only use it when I travel for leisure and order online.

This looks like a scam, but if you know well your sister-in-law, it may not be.